# My query in not presenting the results of the xml

Tags: xml, xquery

I am trying to do a query for my work that shows the name of a producer after searching for is code. When i try to run the query it doesn't show any result. Any help?
PS- I am using BaseX to run the querys

QUERY

```
for $x in 
doc("macaMoimenta.xml")/moimenta/produtores/produtor
where $x/codigo="PR001" 
return $x/nome
```

My XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="style_macaMoimenta.xsl"?>
<moimenta xmlns="http://www.macamoimenta.pt/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:gnr="http://www.macamoimenta.pt/general" xmlns:clt="http://www.macamoimenta.pt/lote"
xmlns:prc="http://www.macamoimenta.pt/precario"
xmlns:clb="http://www.macamoimenta.pt/calibragem"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.macamoimenta.pt/ moimenta.xsd">
<produtores>
    <produtor>
        <codigo>PR001</codigo>
        <nome>Antonio Manuel</nome>
        <data_registo>2018-03-20</data_registo>
        <morada>
            <gnr:rua>Rua Antonio Manuel</gnr:rua>
            <gnr:numero>69</gnr:numero>
            <gnr:cod_postal>4569-123</gnr:cod_postal>
        </morada>
        <colheita ano="2018" qualidade="Ambrosia">
            <cod_colheita>FE23569</cod_colheita>
            <valor>
                <prc:preco_valor valor="0-60">
                    <prc:preco>0.10</prc:preco>
                </prc:preco_valor>
                <prc:preco_valor valor="60-65">
                    <prc:preco>0.13</prc:preco>
                </prc:preco_valor>
                <prc:preco_valor valor="65-70">
                    <prc:preco>0.17</prc:preco>
                </prc:preco_valor>
                <prc:preco_valor valor="DEFEITO">
                    <prc:preco>0.05</prc:preco>
                </prc:preco_valor>
            </valor>
            <lotes>
                <lote>
                    <clt:n_lote>236598</clt:n_lote>
                    <clt:quantidade>2500</clt:quantidade>
                    <clt:calibragem>
                        <clb:calib valor="0-60">
                            <clb:quantidade>1000</clb:quantidade>
                        </clb:calib>
                        <clb:calib valor="60-65">
                            <clb:quantidade>1300</clb:quantidade>
                        </clb:calib>
                        <clb:calib valor="DEFEITO">
                            <clb:quantidade>200</clb:quantidade>
                        </clb:calib>
                    </clt:calibragem>
                </lote>
            </lotes>
        </colheita>

    </produtor>
</produtores>
```

I don't understand why it's not working because everything looks well. 
Thank You very much! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prefix your query with

```
declare default element namespace "http://www.macamoimenta.pt/";
```

(see https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#id-default-namespace) and you will find that the paths start to select something.

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPgCcon has an online sample although https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPgCcon/1 which uses `return data($x/nome)` instead of `return $x/nome` might be more obvious to show the result.

Comment: thank you very much! Can i just ask why do i need to put the `declare default element namespace "http://www.macamoimenta.pt/";` before?

Comment: The default namespace declaration `xmlns="http://www.macamoimenta.pt/"` on the root element of your input document puts all the elements with names without prefixes in that namespace `http://www.macamoimenta.pt/` and to select elements in a namespace you need to declare it in XQuery, without that the paths like `moimenta/produtores/produtor` select such elements in no namespace (e.g. if your XML didn't have the `xmlns="http://www.macamoimenta.pt/"`).