# My XSL in not presenting the data in the xml

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to do an xsl to present my xml file, but it's not showing the data in the xml file.

XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0"
xmlns:datetime="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h2>Maçã de Moimenta</h2>

            <div>
                <xsl:for-each select="moimenta/produtores">

                    <!-- 1º tabela -->

                    <table border="1">
                        <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                            <th>Relatório: CC / Fornecedor: </th>
                            <th>Data: </th>
                            <th>Ano Fiscal: </th>
                            <th>Colheita: </th>
                            <th>Qualidade da Maça: </th>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td/>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="produtor/nome"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="datetime:dateTime()"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>></td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="produtor/colheita/@ano"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="produtor/colheita/cod_colheita"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="produtor/colheita/@qualidade"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    </table>

                    <!-- Tabela Dados da calibragem -->

                    <div> Dados de Calibragem: </div>
                    <div>
                        <table border="1">

                            <tr>
                                <th>Número do Lote:</th>
                                <th>Quantidade Total:</th>
                                <xsl:for-each select="produtor/colheita">
                                    <th>Calibragem: <xsl:value-of
                                            select="valor/preço_valor/@valor"/></th>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </tr>

                            <xsl:for-each select="produtor/colheita/lotes">

                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="lote/n_lote"/>
                                    </td>

                                    <xsl:for-each select="lote/calibragem">
                                        <td>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="calib/quantidade"/>
                                        </td>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </tr>

                            </xsl:for-each>

                        </table>

                        <!-- FALTA INFORMAÇÃO SOBRE O QUE FALTA CALIBRAR -->
                    </div>


                    <!-- Tabela Resumo -->

                    <div>Resumo: </div>

                    <table border="1">

                        <tr>
                            <th>Número do Lote:</th>
                            <th>Calibragem:</th>
                            <th>Percentagem:</th>
                        </tr>

                        <xsl:for-each select="produtor/colheita/lotes">

                            <tr>
                                <!-- coloquei 5 porque restringi os valores de calibragem até 4 valores -->
                                <th rowspan="5">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="lote/n_lote"/>
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                            <xsl:for-each select="lote">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="calibragem/calib/@valor"/>
                                    </th>
                                    <th><xsl:value-of
                                            select="(calibragem/calib/quantidade div quantidade) * 100"
                                        />%</th>
                                </tr>
                            </xsl:for-each>

                        </xsl:for-each>

                    </table>


                </xsl:for-each>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="style_macaMoimenta.xsl"?>
<moimenta xmlns="http://www.macamoimenta.pt/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:gnr="http://www.macamoimenta.pt/general" xmlns:clt="http://www.macamoimenta.pt/lote"
xmlns:prc="http://www.macamoimenta.pt/precario"
xmlns:clb="http://www.macamoimenta.pt/calibragem"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.macamoimenta.pt/ moimenta.xsd">
<produtores>
    <produtor>
        <codigo>PR001</codigo>
        <nome>Antonio Manuel</nome>
        <data_registo>2018-03-20</data_registo>
        <morada>
            <gnr:rua>Rua Antonio Manuel</gnr:rua>
            <gnr:numero>69</gnr:numero>
            <gnr:cod_postal>4569-123</gnr:cod_postal>
        </morada>
        <colheita ano="2018" qualidade="Ambrosia">
            <cod_colheita>FE23569</cod_colheita>
            <valor>
                <prc:preco_valor valor="0-60">
                    <prc:preco>0.10</prc:preco>
                </prc:preco_valor>
                <prc:preco_valor valor="60-65">
                    <prc:preco>0.13</prc:preco>
                </prc:preco_valor>
                <prc:preco_valor valor="65-70">
                    <prc:preco>0.17</prc:preco>
                </prc:preco_valor>
                <prc:preco_valor valor="DEFEITO">
                    <prc:preco>0.05</prc:preco>
                </prc:preco_valor>
            </valor>
            <lotes>
                <lote>
                    <clt:n_lote>236598</clt:n_lote>
                    <clt:quantidade>2500</clt:quantidade>
                    <clt:calibragem>
                        <clb:calib valor="0-60">
                            <clb:quantidade>1000</clb:quantidade>
                        </clb:calib>
                        <clb:calib valor="60-65">
                            <clb:quantidade>1300</clb:quantidade>
                        </clb:calib>
                        <clb:calib valor="DEFEITO">
                            <clb:quantidade>200</clb:quantidade>
                        </clb:calib>
                    </clt:calibragem>
                </lote>
            </lotes>
        </colheita>
    </produtor>
</produtores>
</moimenta>
```

Mostly I just need to show some information that it's on the xml in the xsl file. You can understand by the things i am requesting for the xsl file to show with the xml, i dont know why it's not showing what i need.
Can you help me please???

Answer (score 0):

You have problems with your namespaces - you don't take them into account.
And you have a problem with your XSLT version:
you are using *exslt* features in an XSLT-1.0 stylesheet.
You can't do that, because most browsers (unfortunately) only support the strict version 1.0. As a general rule, *exslt* features are not supported by all browsers, so you have to remove/transform them.

Fixing both problems you XML could look like this (partial response):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:pt="http://www.macamoimenta.pt/"                              <!-- Adding root stylesheet with prefix 'pt' -->
exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="1.0"
xmlns:datetime="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h2>Maçã de Moimenta</h2>    
            <div>
                <xsl:for-each select="pt:moimenta/pt:produtores">   <!-- Use namespaces -->
...
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="datetime:dateTime()"/>          <!-- this empression has to be replaced by an XSLT-1.0 compatible version -->
            </td>
...
```

If you can fix these issues, the stylesheet/XML should work.

Comment: I tried to do the way you said but it's not working. Why i have to use the prefix in the xsl if i don't use it in the xml?

Comment: Because `xmlns="..."` sets the default namespace on your XML root element (inherited by all sub-elements). To access those elements properly in XSLT-1.0, you have to give the namespace a name, like `pt`. This can only be avoided in higher XSLT version like 2.0 or above by using the `xpath-default-namespace` attribute. But because you seem to target browsers (which only support XSLT-1.0) this not practicable

Comment: i tried to search for another solutions for the current date:time but i only found <script> soomething that i can't use in this project, do you know any compatible way to do it in xslt 1.0?

Comment: I haven't searched all possibilities, but [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bxslt%5D+dateTime%28%29) delivers a lot of approaches.

Answer (score 0):

XSLT and XQuery share XPath as the expresion language and in [My query in not presenting the results of the xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52016131/my-query-in-not-presenting-the-results-of-the-xml) you already learned that a path expression like `moimenta/produtores` selects elements of those names in no namespace, if your XML didn't have the `xmlns="http://www.macamoimenta.pt/" default namespace declaration.

In XSLT 2 or 3 you have the posibility of setting e.g. `xpath-default-namespace="http://www.macamoimenta.pt/"` (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#unprefixed-qnames) to change that.

As with XQuery, if you have input documents with elements from different namespace (like your `prc:preco_valor` elements) you need to declare them in the XSLT as well to select them in that namespace.

Comment: I learned that and for example i didn't use the namespace in `moimenta/produtores` in the xml file, do i need to use it in the xsl file?

Comment: Please search for "XSLT default namespace" and read some of the answers - there are hundreds of them, and they all essentially say the same thing.